# Java - Apply different logic based on a field of a generic type

Tags: java

I have the following class. I have placed my question inside the code.

```
public class Spec<E> implements Specification<E> {

  @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<E> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, 
                      CriteriaBuilder builder, String key) {

     // I need to check if the string "key" is a a declared field of the type E, 
     // and if the Java type of the field is ZonedDateTime, apply a different 
     // logic

    // How can I do this ? 

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you pass in a `Class<E>` when you construct one?

Comment: `// I need to check if the string "key" is a a declared field of the type E` Use reflection? `// and if the Java type of the field is ZonedDateTime` Use reflection? `// How can I do this ?` Use reflection?

Comment: @user2478398 I think he's using Spring JPA, so he can't pass the class in - see https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was able to do this passing it into my builder class.